# ASP.NET Core. Configure DI to get the same object for different interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have middleware, that do some job and create object. I need to inject this object into controller. 
So far I see solution with extra layer by adding to DI some factory that create such objects by extracting already created one from `context.Items['myobject_created_and_placed_here_in_middleware']`.

Also I'm considering another way:

```
public interface IReader
{
    string Get();
}

public interface IWriter
{
    string Set(string value);
}

public class Object1 : IReader, IWriter
{
    public string s1 { get; set; }
    public string Get()
    {
        return this.s1;
    }

    public string Set(string value)
    {
        this.s1 = value;
        return s1;
    }
}

public class Middleware1
{
    RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IReader _reader;


    public Middleware1(RequestDelegate next, IReader reader)
    {
        this.next = next;
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var test1 = _reader.Get();
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public class Middleware2
{
    RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IWriter _writer;


    public Middleware2(RequestDelegate next, IWriter writer)
    {
        this.next = next;
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        _writer.Set("13168AAE-C886-453E-B655-ECE5D14645D9");
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        app.UseMiddleware<Middleware2>();
        app.UseMiddleware<Middleware1>();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
```

So far it doesn't work.
This returns different objects:

```
services.AddScoped<IReader,Object1>();
services.AddScoped<IWriter, Object1>();
```

This can't resolve interface:

```
services.AddScoped<Object1>();
```

The question is: how to register it in DI and get the same object for different interfaces per request.

Comment: The factory is really your only choice, since most DI containers are designed around the identification of objects by their type.  If you give it two types, it will create two different objects.  That's why custom factory calls exist for DI containers, because sometimes the automated, simple methods don't work for all situations.

Comment: @juunas I believe it's not. I'm asking about passing object created in middleware to controller and suggested few thoughts on this. Since this  object should be created per request (to go throughout entire pipeline) I don't see duplication here.

Comment: Hmm, true. I may have been a bit hasty with the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would stick with the `Items` property in the `HttpContext`, as its sole purpose is storing items for the scope of a request.

If, however, you would like to use an object instance in DI I suggest you merge the `IReader` and `IWriter` into a single interface and add that to the DI container.

Comment: So, I can create `interface ICompose: IReader , IWriter`. However, I should (??) use this `ICompose` in my controller/middleware and then use casting (but it doesn't have any sense then). I want avoid such thing. Since nobody can get answer from pocket, I assume my logic is not so popular and as result it didn't supported in standard way by asp.net core, thus I have to use Items.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: it is possible to share a single object between DI registrations, even between `Scoped` and `Transient` registrations. Try to avoid it if possible.

```
public interface IGodObject { } //empty marker interface
public interface IWriter { }
public interface IReader { }
public class GodObject : IGodObject, IReader, IWriter { }

services.AddScoped<IGodObject>(p =>
{
    return new GodObject();
});

services.AddScoped<IReader>(p =>
{
    return p.GetService<IGodObject>() as IReader;
});

services.AddScoped<IWriter>(p =>
{
    return p.GetService<IGodObject>() as IWriter;
});
```

Comment: Nice tip. This should be marked as the answer. You can also make all these registrations one liners by removing curly braces and 'return' keyword. Also the very first registration can simply be `services.AddScoped<IGodObject, GodObject>()`